# GPU can't detect by tensorflow-gpu 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras

GPU can't detect by tensorflow-gpu 2.0, what is the problem?
for

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

output is below in my computer with Ubuntu 16.04

```
True
False
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 10185800011826802770, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_CPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 2908743746130792497
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device", name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_GPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 13796634005997726084
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device", name: "/device:XLA_GPU:1"
 device_type: "XLA_GPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 4940094218016527544
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device", name: "/device:XLA_GPU:2"
 device_type: "XLA_GPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 15391692776259568109
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device", name: "/device:XLA_GPU:3"
 device_type: "XLA_GPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 8368387340417357161
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"]
```

Comment: Just a guess: does your cuda version match the build version of TF?

Comment: @y.selivonchyk bingo, it works now after installing cuda 10.0

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by y.selivonchyk, it works now after installing cuda 10.0. Not easy to go there though (involve uninstalling/reinstallling nvidia driver and cuda), if anyone needs help, let me know in comments.